# Android: set elevation for above element (shadow with up direction)

Tags: android, layout, material-design, android-elevation

What's the correct way to get this shadow between the footer buttons and the main scrollview?

[image: Chrome example]

This is my current layout:

[image: Schematic layout]

Applying an elevation attribute to the latest RelativeLayout doesn't work:

Comment: This is the default shadow appear on scrollview in android l

Comment: Nope it's not in fact the one you are talking about is radial and appears only when the bottom is reached. As you can see in the 1st picture above the scrollbar hasn't reached the bottom yet

http://i.imgur.com/sP718Zf.jpg

Comment: @filippo did you figure out how to do it?